# When someone owes money everyone

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, register

There is a sentence which says "[He owes money left and right.](http://ww.africansupermarket.com/store/africansupermarket_39254863_B000LZKTVY.htm)" which says has has borrowed money from almost everyone. I would appreciate it if someone could let me know if the following sentence sounds natural as the mentioned sentence of mine:

> - He is indebted money to left and right.

I guess the word "money" is redundant, because it can be implied by the verb itself. Please explain it to me from a native speaker's point of view.

Comment: I would take out "money to." But the original sounds more natural.

Comment: There would be something of a register-clash when mixing "indebted" with "left and right".

Answer (score 2):

***[Indebted](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indebted)*** is an adjective that means:

> - committed or obligated to repay a monetary loan:
>
>   - *He was indebted to his friend for a large sum*.

(Dictionary.com)

The idea that money is owed to someone is already included in the meaning of the term.
 So you would say: *He is indebted left and right*.

***[Left and right](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/left+and+right)*** is an idiomatic expression meaning everywhere:

> - everywhere, without any plan or pattern *People are complaining left and right about the new parking regulations.*

(The Free Dictionary)

"Owe money" sounds more colloquial than "be indebted", but the meaning is the same